# How do I alter my C code to use pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

The task was at first to return the index of the first instance of any character in `stop` within `string`:

```
int find_any_index(char string[], char stop[]) {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while(string[i++] != '\0'){
        while(stop[j++] != '\0'){

            if(string[i-1] == stop[j-1]){
                return i-1;
            }
        }
        j = 0;
    }
    return NOT_FOUND ;
}
```

`find_any_index("abcdefg", "zyd")` for example, finds index 3.

However, I now need to do this same task with the following stipulations:

- Cannot use integers
- Cannot use array indexing
- Cannot use any functions from `<string.h>`
- Returns a pointer rather than the index

```
char *find_any_ptr(char *string, char* stop) {
    return NULL ;   // placeholder
}
```

I barely understand pointers and don't understand how to use them to access the individual characters instead of incrementing in the array.

Comment: Remember that `a[b]` is the same as `*(a+b)` and the rest is easy

Comment: Can't use integers? Comparing `char`s is comparing integers... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will use character pointers in this case. Here you will check each char in `string` against each char in `stop`. When any char in `stop` is matched, return a pointer to the position in `string`. If no match is found (return either `string` or `NULL`, example returns `NULL`) Example:

```
char *find_any_index(char string[], char stop[]) {

    char *p = string;
    char *sp = NULL;

    while (*p)
    {
        sp = stop;
        while (*sp)
        {
            if (*sp == *p)
                return p;
            sp++;
        }
        p++;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a skeleton of what your function should look like:

```
char* find_any_index(char string[], char stop[])
{
    char* cp1 = string;
    char* cp2 = NULL;

    for ( ; *cp1 != '\0'; ++cp1 )
    {
       for ( cp2 = stop; *cp2 != '\0'; ++cp2 )
       {
       }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

I think you can finish the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no matter what there will always be integers in this task. `char` and `unsigned char` are types of integers. I assume the task is to produce efficient code, free of unnecessary variables (integers or otherwise).

By first iterating on `stop` we can build a lookup table. Each bit in the table will correspond to whether or not the character at the bit's position is present in `stop`.

```
unsigned char table[CHAR_MAX / CHAR_BIT + 1] = { 0 };
while (*stop) {
    unsigned char c = *stop++;
    table[c / CHAR_BIT] |= 1 << c % CHAR_BIT;
}
```

This reduces the inner loop to a single bit test, reducing the constant time complexity from `O(mn)` to `O(m+n)`.

```
while (*string) {
    unsigned char c = *string;
    if (table[c / CHAR_BIT] & (1 << c % CHAR_BIT)) {
        return string;
    }
    string++;
}
```

Technically, `c` is an unnecessary variable (and an integer), however by using `c` in each of these pieces of code I eliminated two casts, which improves the legibility of this code. I'd consider that to be more important.

Answer (score -2):

You can start with the fact that in C, a[1] is equivalent to *(a+1).
The restriction "Cannot use integers" may indicate that you should use the type "char" instead. It acts like an integer but is restricted to 8bit range (0-255).

Comment: I think they mean use `*ptr`, `ptr++`, etc. to do all the work.

Comment: That's what I said, no idea what are the down-votes for... I tried to give him a hint so that he can think about the problem on his own :)

Comment: Because that's not what you said.  `*(a+1)` uses an integer and is effectively an indexed lookup rather than a direct pointer dereference.

Comment: You can also say that 1 is a char and thus legit, but I agree that it's not what they probably ment.

Comment: You could, but you'd be wrong.  Integers are numbers; limiting the range of values to 0-255 does not make it a non-integer.  We're talking the mathematical definition of the word, not the C "int" definition of the word.  Besides, the literal "1" is an "int", always.